# Cant raise event on image mouse enter

Tags: wpf

On my wpf form i have image and toggle button controls. 
On image mouse over i want to raise event to the toggle button - this event will actully will simulate the mouser enter to the toggle button.

For some reason i get crash on the raiseEvent.

The code:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".9*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToggleButton Name="toggleBtn"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Content="...test..." VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" />

    <Image Name="imgCtrl" Grid.Row="0" Source="someImg.jpg" Stretch="Fill" MouseEnter="imgMouseEnter_Event" />


</Grid>
```

The code that thru the event

```
    private void imgMouseEnter_Event( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        toggleBtn.RaiseEvent( new RoutedEventArgs( ToggleButton.MouseEnterEvent ) );
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it show any exception details when crashing? Post them.

Comment: No - just quick crash ... all the debug exeption handle are checked.

Comment: ok, i got some exection now Object of type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs'.

Comment: So, now you know what's going wrong. But, I am still curious what you are trying to achieve and if this is the best way.

Comment: IS there other way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private void imgMouseEnter_Event(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouse = new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0);
        mouse.RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseEnterEvent;
        toggleBtn.RaiseEvent(mouse);

    }
```